# ASP.NET MVC Web API Authentication Token Security Issues

Tags: api, security, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am developing a asp.net mvc project with Web API. Web API will be consumed by Website, mobile apps and third party. Now, on some APIs will be called on Home page only without any login and same APIs will be called after login only.

Now, considering my website scenario, I have called APIs from AngularJs. We called an api which will generate a token on session_start. Then from NG we called a mvc controller method which will simply get that token and then the token will passed in HTTP-Header in All requests.

On API side, we fetch the token, decrypt it and show result.

Problem is, when I see Google Chrome's Network Tab (press F12) I can easily see API Calls and even Token in headers. I feel security vulnerability. For Open APIs, we thought of having some expiry time and request counts. But some APIs will be sensitive, like adding data in DB(POST APIs, based on data passed as parameters) and they also will be available to Guest Users. We don't want someone to misuse it and do harmful things.

How can we achieve maximum security in this scenario? What will be ideal security process?

Comment: The security does not rely on hiding the API structure (method names, data format, etc...), but on giving access to those APIs only to authorized clients, which is what your tokens should do. In other words if your tokens are cryptographically sound (cannot be spoofed or faked), your connection is protected (nobody can intercept your tokens) and your backend correctly authenticates and authorizes your clients, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To further explain Marco Sandrini's comment...

> The security does not rely on hiding the API structure (method names, data format, etc...), but on giving access to those APIs only to authorized clients, which is what your tokens should do. In other words if your tokens are cryptographically sound (cannot be spoofed or faked), your connection is protected (nobody can intercept your tokens) and your backend correctly authenticates and authorizes your clients, you should be fine.

The token should not be subject to replay attacks. The server should already be expecting a different permutation of the token for subsequent requests, and you shouldn't know how to produce that by reading the token.

Proper SSL/TLS will protect the content of the connection from prying eyes. If your guest users can see *other's* sensitive information in *their Chrome network tab*, then you should worry because something has gone wrong with your implementation strategy.